# Reference checklist for starting a new Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

It's easy to create a new Rails application using "rails new myapp" (or start with a template from Rails Wizard or the RailsApps project).

But after that, what do you do? What gems do you always add? What decisions do you make before beginning development? What important items are often overlooked before deploying an app?

I'd like to put together a reference checklist to share. Any suggestions?

For example:

- Create a new RVM gemset
- Modify the .gitignore file
- Switch from TestUnit to RSpec
- Set up Guard to run tests in the background during development
- Add the viewport metatag to the default application layout
- Don't forget to create a sitemap.xml file
- Add a Google Analytics snippet

What else?

Comment: That really depends on your specific requirements. In a lot of cases I wouldn't do half of the things you mention.

Comment: Add a humans.txt along side robots.txt

Comment: I think that sitemap and google analytics are not Rails specific components. It is optional and probably only relevant for launching a site in production - therefore, it is only required at the very final step of application development.

Answer (score 9):

Starting with a Rails template.

You should look theses resources :

- http://railswizard.org/
- https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates
- http://railsapps.github.com/rails-application-templates.html
- https://github.com/quickleft/prologue

Comment: I'm the OP. I created the RailsApps application templates (derived from Rails Wizard recipes). I'm asking for suggestions for a checklist because the templates are not complete. I often add my own stuff and I'm wondering what other people often add.

Comment: I agree, I always adding my stuff on existing rails template application so I've started working on my own rail templates (with login, openid, forget password, role permissions, html5, requirejs, jquery, test..).

Answer (score 6):

For me usual process involves:

- Add CSS framework (grids, text, forms)
- Add Cells
- Add Slim (www.slim-lang.com)
- Remove Test::Unit for RSpec
- Add application config settings (config.yml)
- Add Cucumber
- Add FactoryGirl
- Add Spork
- Add Guard (guard-rspec, guard-cucumber, guard-sass, guard-livereload, guard-spork)
- Add Git, Github space, + amend .gitignore
- Add Heroku (stage + production) spaces

I'll usually copy over my google_analytics helpers and sitemap_controller from other projects during the development process instead of being organised enough to do it from the start. I like to the the testing and deployment options setup from the get go so I can start developing and releasing early and often.

Dave

Answer (score 3):

create rvm gemset, create .rvmrc, modify .gitignore

Then add gems

- gem 'pg'
- gem 'thin'
- gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
- gem 'rspec-rails'
- gem 'factory_girl_rails'
- gem 'capybara'

then depending on the project, I often use aws3, paperclip, resque, will_paginate and haml (although I try not to use it on new projects anymore)

Comment: Why are you no longer using Haml?

Comment: @DanielKehoe for me Haml is to Html what CoffeeScript is to javascript and Sass to CSS, so not seeing it included with Rails 3.1 somewhat influenced my choice to not use it anymore (I bet they had their reasons.) Also I experienced some problems because Haml overrides some methods of the output buffer, so you deal with yet another layer of complex. In short, I try to stick to the best practices.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time:

1. Configuration

   - add .rvmrc
   - amberbit-config gem (avaible at GH)
   - modify .gitignore
2. Views

   - haml to sass/coffee stack
   - rdiscount
3. Tests

   - rspec instead of unit tests
   - capybara, factory_gril, spork, timecop
4. Development

   - guard-livereload, with guard, libnotify etc.
   - active_reload for faster development with assets pipeline
   - annotate if relational db
   - pry

---

I almost forgot to mention: mix of html5 boilerplate for rails with twitter bootstrap it's good combo.

Comment: The amberbit-config gem seems a little overkill for something that could be done using just 2 lines of code to load a yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

The first think that I do is head to http://railswizard.org/ and create a template, before "rails new app".

Comment: I like to build a generic template using Rails Wizard, then fork it on Github and add my own stuff (guard, etc...) that Rails Wizard does not add by default.

Answer (score 1):

- I always want to set up [Factory Girl](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) under /fixtures, and setup
  Cucumber along Rspec. Sometimes I use shoulda too.
- Initialize the project as a git repository and link it to
  [github](https://github.com/). Set up the app to use [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) instead of SQLite.
- And last I can think of is that I often make an entry, from the
  beginning, to load .rb files form /lib automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't add anything. Things get added if project requires them.

- I don't load up CSS framework just because there's a need for two columns and a rounded button somewhere.
- I don't load FactoryGirl because rails test fixtures actually do a fine job as long as you know how to use them. (Hint: you don't need 100 instances of User in your fixtures)
- I don't load RSpec/Cucumber/etc because UnitTest is just as good and I prefer keeping things simple.

There's absolutely no reason to bloat project with things just because you "might need it"

Answer (score 1):

I got tired of having to remember and repeat the mundane tasks required for every new app.

If you're looking for guidance on getting started, we've recently (yesterday!) released a tool to speed up the process, with all sorts of tried and tested libraries for the various aspects of a Rails web app, as well as cleanup scripts to get the fresh app just the way it should be.

Check out http://drone.bz to build an app the same way we do. Under the hood, it uses the [app_drone](https://github.com/jeriko/app_drone) gem to resolve dependencies and build the actual template, but the UI is probably all you need to get started.

There are several similar tools out there, but I decided to be highly opinionated in my recipe choices, and the end result is a solid foundation on which to start developing :)

P.S. Even if you don't use the drones, you can take a look at the steps that are common enough in Rails dev to be automated.